# saving roi in imageJ without prompt window

Tags: imagej

When I try to save a roi in imagej using the code below, a window prompts to save the roi. However, I want to save the roi programmatically so that I can do it for several different files. How can I avoid the prompt window and how can give each roi a specific name (the whole file is saved with the name RoiSet which contain several roi that each should have a different name I choose)?

```
rm.runCommand("Save", IJ.getDirectory(r"path to my folder") + "RoiSet.zip")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that [`IJ.getDirectory(String)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/ImageJ1/ij/IJ.html#getDirectory-java.lang.String-) returns null, so your path becomes `nullRoiSet.zip`, which ImageJ thinks is not a valid path, and therefore it prompts with a dialog box.

You do not need the `IJ.getDirectory` call here; just pass `r"path to my folder\RoiSet.zip"` directly and it should work without popping any dialogs.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not using the macro language, which might make things a tad more difficult, but I'm not an expert by any means, so take that assumption with a grain of salt. If you do decide to switch and use the macro language, you can simply wrap your code in the batch mode function like so:

```
setBatchMode(true);
example code here;
setBatchMode(false);
```

As for saving, the macro language uses the saveAs() function, which takes file type and save path + title of the file as arguments. If you want more info about, or help writing in, the macro language, let me know and we can likely put something together rather quickly.